# Rails: upload a file OR store a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing a form where I want to allow users to either upload a file, or enter a url to an existing file.

The idea is to allow users to attach various 'multimedia' files to entries, some of which may be files from their hard drives (think images, word documents, etc) and some may be urls (youtube videos, images on flickr, etc)

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I'm currently using carrierwave to handle file uploads, and it seems to work well, but I want to store url's as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I will probably do is to have a drop down in the file upload form to select if the file is from the disk or from external url.

By default it will set to "from disk", and if they select external url, you could use some AJAX magic and hide the file upload text box and have a text box to use the external url/script etc..

in the table, you can keep another two columns,

1 - external url

2 - file category (external / uploaded file)

by that way you can distinguish the files and how they what to display in the view

HTH

Comment: This is probably what I will end up doing. I was just wondering if there was a magical gem out there to handle it ;)

Comment: @bstamour, glad it helped, There is no magic gem as far as I know, but you could give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't save the url unless you really have too. The thing is that when you save a url, you can't process it to create a thumbnail or multiple styles of the image. Also, when you display the images in a page you will have to make external calls and that can slow down the page or even worse, if the link breaks sometime in the future your users will see an empty image.

Which is also the case with youtube videos. However, with videos you typically want to store and display more information than just the video. You can have two tables - one for videos and one for images. In the video table you have title, desc, author, duration, embed code, thumbnail (image attachment).

You can download any image when a URL is given and save it like a normal file.
Using carrierwave -

```
@object.remote_image_url = "http://www.foo.com/file.png"
@object.save
```

In the view, you would have both options, perhaps side by side and you can let them post to different actions. So if a file is selected and posted you save it normally. If a url is entered, then you can check if it's a video site or not - if video, parse out the info using the video_info gem and store it. Otherwise just use the two lines above and save the url image.

**Note**

My answer doesn't discuss the quality / nature of user inputs. The likely-hood of someone entering an incorrect url is high in my opinion, so you want to wrap attempts to save the url as an image in a begin-rescue block and perhaps using JS limit the video domains to just a few websites which you will be able to parse.

Comment: That's good advise for the case of images, but what about youtube videos and the like?

Comment: @bstamour videos are not images :) Regardless, you should keep a separate set of columns or even a different table for videos. Check out https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info it will parse a Vimeo or Youtube url and return stuff like title, desc, thumbnail, embed code, etc which you can then store in the database

Comment: "The thing is that when you save a url, you can't process it to create a thumbnail or multiple styles of the image." Sure you can. You can run background processes to cURL the images and process them. Carrierwave does that (and I'm assuming Paperclip does as well).

Comment: @tadiou I meant there is no need to save the URL to the database. Paperclip runs processes on the image asynchronously, so does carrierwave. All of which is to say that the original URL value has little value once you save the record and shouldn't ideally be referenced anywhere else in the app. Also, unless very high volume, rolling your own bckgrnd que has problems - what if the url breaks / site goes down / image is changed at that address, etc. Unless you know how soon after saving the cURL would run.