# two fields for one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my form I have field for file uploading which is done with default rails methods, looking like this(I'm using simple_form here, to be clear):

```
= f.input :spec_url, as: :file
```

It generates nice and easily field with which user can select any file from his hard drive. But i would like to give users opportunity to simply type this information. since this is field for URL, it should be string field, possible to just fill in, WITH POSSIBILITY to upload something.
How can I achieve this? Some gems maybe?

Comment: I think a `file` will send an object, not a string. Specifying a string will not be able to access the user's filesystem unless it's a URL.

Comment: but it is supposed be url so i think its fine. either string or this object... so what do i do?:)

Comment: do you want either to save the remoted file on the server or just store link to the file?

Comment: yes, well this link does not need to point any file, but in general, yes, thats what i need

Comment: Leo, which one is it? Upload the file to the server or store the link on a record? Or both?

Comment: both. look we have a field(lets call it urlField), placeholder: "url". you can type url from keyboard eg "stackoverflow.com" and next to it is 'browse' button, whichc allows you to pick a file up from hard drive nad it magically appears in the urlField as eg. 'stackoverflow.html'

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have two fields (a string and a file):

```
= f.input :spec_url, as: :string, id: 'url-field'
= f.input :spec_file, as: :file, id: 'file-field'
```

Add some javascript (I'm using CoffeeScript) which will set the file name on the `spec_url` field:

```
$ ->
  $('#file-field').on 'change', (e) =>
    $('#url-field').val($(e.target).val())
```

And then you can do some conditional statements in your Ruby code:

```
if params[:object][:spec_file]
  # Upload file
  object.spec_url = params[:object][:spec_file].original_filename
else
  # Open URL
  object.spec_url = params[:object][:spec_url]
end
```

Add `attr_accessor :spec_file` to your model:

```
attr_accessor :spec_file
```

This is just a rough idea since I'm not sure what the context is. You might need to modify and style some of the code.

**Update**

You might also find this question helpful: [Rails: upload a file OR store a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547724/rails-upload-a-file-or-store-a-url)

Comment: its most obvious solution, but not exactly what i nedd

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i want a single input. string field in which chosen file will appear if user decides to choose any