# Rails: how to store and display image using external url from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, api

I can store the external image URL from the API response, and display it in view. But I am having trouble understanding how to store the the actual image so I can display it without calling the full external URL each time.

These are some of the resources I've looked at: [Rails: upload a file OR store a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547724/rails-upload-a-file-or-store-a-url) and http://code.runnable.com/UnsMH7fYN2V6AAAT/how-to-save-images-by-url-with-paperclip-for-ruby-on-rails-and-upload.

This is what I have so far:

```
# this is used for file upload from create form 
has_attached_file :ephoto, :styles => { :medium => "480x270#",  :small => "240x135#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

    if group_response.nil?
    else 
      group_response.each do |group| 
        # stores external image URL into "ephoto_file_name"
        event.update_attribute :ephoto_file_name, group["group_photo"]["photo_link"]
        event.ephoto = open(group["group_photo"]["photo_link"])
      end 
    end
```

The `event.ephoto = open(group["group_photo"]["photo_link"])` does not seem to work properly. Using `<%= image_tag event.ephoto.url %>` just returns broken images.

Display image in view:

```
  <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.ephoto.path.present? && File.exist?(event.ephoto.path) %>
    <%= image_tag event.ephoto.url(:medium) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag 'event-placeholder.png' %>
      <%= image_tag event.ephoto_file_name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The `<%= image_tag event.ephoto_file_name %>` just uses the external URL each time to display the image instead of a stored image.

Is there a better way to display images from API responses? Any suggestions or insights would help. Thanks!

Comment: if you have a read-enabled filesystem you can use wget to save the images to the public directory, store pointers to the images in a lru cache like `lru_redux` and on an interval in a background thread, delete images that aren't in the cache.  But are you sure you need to cache images at all? Unless you're doing some server-size image manipulation there's no need; browsers have a built-in cache and by having clients use the original url you'll be able to take advantage of existing CDN setups.

Comment: If you are hosting image content with a priority for that content not breaking over time I would recommend independently saving image assets into your own cloud storage (e.g. s3) unless the image content is only needed temporarily, or will be processed in such high numbers that storage will be cost prohibitive.  Images from external URL's will break constantly on you, and will become a problem if your content needs to be available for medium-to-longer periods of time.